# Problem with Layout 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

In my layout, I have this string:

```
<block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
```

But I do not have a file in this package in this way.

[image]

But at the same time the code is executed in: `/gamma/template/broadway/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Why? Also in the documentation all examples with `local.xml` are written, but I have 2 layouts with different names. We can call our layout as we want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a template is not present in your theme `gamma` then Magento will use a fallback system to look in the `base` theme. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25777391/7497291).

It's the same for the layout : if you call your layout with the same name as in the base theme,then the one in the base theme will not be used anymore. If you use a different name, your layout will be merged to the others (depending on the order each module is loaded)